# Python program to print the odd and even indices of an string not taking the first test case

Tags: python

**Question**

Given a string S of length N, that is indexed from 0 to N-1, print it's even indexed and odd indexed characters as 2 space separated strings on a single line. Assume input starts at index position 0(which is considered even)

**Input**

The first line contains an integer, T (the number of test cases). Each line i of the T subsequent lines contain a String, S.

**Output**

For each string S, print it's even-indexed characters, followed by space, followed by odd-indexed characters.

**Sample Input**

2

Hacker

Rank

**Sample Output**

Hce akr

Rn ak

**My code is as follows**

```
T=int(input().strip())
for i in range(T):
    Str=(input().strip())
    odd=""
    even=""
    l=len(Str)

    for j in range(l):
        if(j%2==0):
            even += Str[j]
        else:
            odd += Str[j]   
print(even,"",odd)
```

****The output I am getting is:**
Input

2

Hacker

Rank

My Output

Rn  ak

please help me what I am doing wrong?**

Comment: We don't know what the code is supposed to do. Or what the input is. Or what the output is supposed to be

Comment: there are several things wrong here, but the biggest issues are that you define `odd` and `even` INSIDE the loop, move them outside so you dont keep deleting them every iteration

Comment: I've added the details, Hope now you are getting this

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you.

```
T = list(input().split())
for j in T:
    a = ""
    b = ""
    for i in range(0,len(j)):
        if i%2 == 0:
            a = a+j[i]
        else :
            b = b + j[i]
    print(a+" "+b)
```

input:

```
hacker rank
```

output :

```
hce akr
rn ak
```

Comment: But where have you taken the string input from the user? I can't understand this

Comment: 1st line. If you want you can do this T = list(input("enter the words").split()). Here you can input the words as a single input separated by space(as shown in input).